# Start reading a file's content from line N using BASH

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the file temp.txt with the following content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How would you read the file's content starting from line number 3 using BASH so that the output would be like this:

```
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using bash"? Do you just want to cat the file or process it in any way?

Comment: Cat would be great.
I just need the lines starting from line number 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tail -n +3 filename
```

shows all lines, starting from 3 of `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

A bash-only solution (for the sake of fun):

```
#!/bin/bash

C=1

DONE=false

until $DONE ;do
  read LINE || DONE=true

  if [ "$C" -ge "$1" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" $LINE
  fi

  C=$(($C+1))
done
```